# Proof Limit Law

Tags: limits, proof-writing

I need a (sketch of) proof (preferably by delta-epsilon) that:

**1.** If $\lim f(x) = L$, $0 < L < 1$ and $\lim g(x) = \infty$ then $\lim f(x)^{g(x)} = 0$

**2.** If $\lim f(x) = L$, $L > 1$ and $\lim g(x) = \infty$ then $\lim f(x)^{g(x)} = \infty$

**3.** If $\lim f(x) = L$, $L > 0$ and $\lim g(x) = \infty$ then $\lim g(x)^{f(x)} = 0$

All limits are of $x$ approaching an arbitrary number $a$.

Thank you!

Edit: I have that

$0<|x-a|<d_1$ gives $|f(x)-L|<e$ thus $L-e<f(x)<L+e$ and

$0<|x-a|<d_2$ gives $g(x)>M=\log_{L+e} e$.

This gives $f(x)^{g(x)} < (L+e)^{g(x)}$.

Now I need $(L+e)^{g(x)} < (L+e)^{\log_{L+e} e} = e$, but I can't prove $L+e < 1$.

If I can, #2 can be proven with $\frac{1}{L}$ instead of $L$ also.

Comment: \infty${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Please offer some idea of what you've tried on this, or what you know how to do.  If you don't do this, people will be less inclined to help.